# Banner notification based on time

Tags: lightning-web-components, configuration, alert, event-notification-service

We have a requirement where we have to show planned system outages information as a banner. The banner should be visible to users from 4 hours before planned outage time.

What would be the best way to achive this ?

Comment: What have you tried or where are you stuck in implementing it yourself? Feel free to [edit] and share any code you may have, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately Salesforce does not have a banner alert system of this kind to notify users.  You could attempt to create your own for example with LWC, but then you would have to add the component to all the pages where you wish to see the banner.  This would be less than ideal.

Comment: If you don't need a "banner" type message you might be able to utilize Login Flows to alert users during the login process.

Answer (score 1):

4 hours is a pretty short notice for an outage. How long will this outage impact users? How are you locking all of your users out in the outage?

Displaying a banner is tricky, particularly if your org is heavily customized because you then have to apply the banner across apps and sites. An easier approach is probably [login flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow.htm&type=5), which allow you to display a message to users when they log in. You can have the flow run any time a user logs in and use a custom setting (for example) to determine if a user is about to fall into an outage window and display a message to them.

Comment: We finally created a custom LWC which picked up when a notification was active and we added the LWC to the relevant pages.